# Docker instances with MySQL replication and reboot

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, docker

After a reboot of the system with two docker instances with MySQL replication, the slaves always breaks the replication with a Slave_IO ending not running.

Last time I had to redo all the process from scratch (removing the database in the slave and restoring the replication connection copying the master binlog info and database again to the slave) and it went back again to sync.

The problem is that there are some light outages and I don't have a SAI, so it will be rebooting now and then, so this is completely impossible to maintain this way.

Are there any measures to keep everything working and re-syncing after reboot? Or is replication not intended to work after reboots by any means?

Comment: Do you ensure the containers get the same IP addresses after the reboot?

Comment: @mustaccio yes, I have made a docker network with hostnames, so basically I point them to the hostnames not to the addresses to be 100% sure they won't change.

Comment: I asked about _IP addresses_, not hostnames. So, you don't know if IP addresses change or not. That might be the problem.

Comment: @mustaccio IP addresses change 100%, and they will be changing in this box because it how it works (Synology machine). In exchange I could set up hostnames that never change and I set up everything using those hostnames. Why would hostnames would do the same as IP addresses in this scenario?